# What is my syntax error in this mySQL create table statement?

Tags: mysql, create-table

I am typing the following:

```
CREATE TABLE events (
`id` mediumint unsigned not null auto_increment,
`user` varchar(30) not null,
`time` datetime not null,
`duration` decimal(5,2) default 1.0,
`title` tinytext not null,
`location` text default null,
`tag` ENUM(‘red’,’orange’,’yellow’,’green’,’blue’,’violet’,’brown’,’black’) default null,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
FOREIGN KEY (`user`) references users (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and I am getting the following response:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '‘red’,’orange’,’yellow’,’green’,’blue’,’violet’,’brown' at line 8
```

This may be a case of tired eyes, but I am stumped. What is wrong with my enum statement?

Comment: Don't use Word for constructing queries

Comment: @Strawberry I was using Mac's TextEdit, actually, making sure the document was plain text and not rich text.

Comment: Well, you got smart quotes from somewhere!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
`tag` ENUM(‘red’,’orange’,’yellow’,’green’,’blue’,’violet’,’brown’,’black’)
```

To:

```
`tag` ENUM('red', 'orange','yellow','green','blue','violet','brown','black')
```

Comment: Amazing. I thought I was going crazy, but the single quotes used in my text editor in plain text are different from the single quotes parsed in the command line.

Answer (score 2):

Enclose data inside `ENUM` by `Single Quote`

```
CREATE TABLE `events` (
`id` mediumint unsigned not null auto_increment,
`user` varchar(30) not null,
`time` datetime not null,
`duration` decimal(5,2) default 1.0,
`title` tinytext not null,
`location` text default null,
`tag` ENUM('red','orange','yellow','green','blue','violet','brown','black') default null,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
FOREIGN KEY (`user`) references users (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**Note:** `event` is a **MySQL RESERVED KEYWORD**. When you use `MySQL RESERVED KEYWORDS` as identifier enclosing by `backtick` is recommended.

Comment: Thanks. Good note about the reserved keyword.

Comment: Event is not a reserved keyword.

Comment: Thanks, May be I am wrong. But what should be the appropriate term for `event`? [**here**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html) it's stated that event is a keyword.@Strawberry

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with the quotes(`‘red’`) you used for `ENUM` values try this ;)

```
CREATE TABLE events (
`id` mediumint unsigned not null auto_increment,
`user` varchar(30) not null,
`time` datetime not null,
`duration` decimal(5,2) default 1.0,
`title` tinytext not null,
`location` text default null,
`tag` ENUM('red','orange','yellow','green','blue','violet','brown','black') default null,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
FOREIGN KEY (`user`) references users (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And before executing this query make sure that users table exists and have column username;

Answer (score 0):

Use single quote in enum instead of backquote. This worked for me:

```
CREATE TABLE events ( `id` mediumint unsigned not null auto_increment, `user` varchar(30) not null, `time` datetime not null, `duration` decimal(5,2) default 1.0, `title` tinytext not null, `location` text default null, `tag` ENUM('red','orange','yellow','green','blue','violet','brown','black') default null,  PRIMARY KEY (`id`), FOREIGN KEY (`user`) references users (`username`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
`tag` ENUM(‘red’,’orange’,’yellow’,’green’,’blue’,’violet’,’brown’,’black’)
```

To

```
`tag` ENUM('red','orange','yellow','green','blue','violet','brown','black')
```

Use '' in case of ‘’ .